# Buying a car in Europe while being a non-resident possible in Holland

Tags: europe

I would like to emphasise the possibility to BUY and subsequently OWN a car for your European roadtrip as being a perfect alternative for renting or leasing. Google for "backpackercars" and "europe" and you will find them in Holland. They give you a temporary license plate, registered at your name, and because the pay the insurance and road tax in advance, you do not need an address in the EU. After use, you can sell it anywhere in the EU as the Union is in fact one big tax zone. Happy driving...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while travel-related, this is not a question.

Comment: @david Actually, it's spam. Flag it rather then VTC.